# Angular Material mat-icon-button, vertically align text in Ionic

Tags: css, angular, cordova, ionic4

I am developing an iOS and Android application using Ionic-Cordova and Angular.

Using the web view to test the app, shows a correct alignment of the Text inside of the button, but when the appplication runs on a mobile( I tested this only on Andorid platform), the Text isn't centered.
I am using a Custom Font to show images using simple text instead of images.

I tried to modify the css code for the span inside of the button, obtaining the same result... correct displaying on web, and wrong one on the native app.

Some Html code:

```
<div class="rightBar">
    <button mat-icon-button class="customFontH right_rightMiddleAlign">
      K
    </button>
</div>
```

```
.rightBar
{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 100%;
  clear:both;

}

.right_rightMiddleAlign
{

  position: absolute;
  left : 100%;
  top: 50%;

  transform: translate3d(-100%, -50% ,0);

}

.customFontH
{
  font-family: customFontName;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 150%;
}

:host ::ng-deep span.mat-button-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50% ,0) !important;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

This is how the web view looks like (Correct Result):

[image: correct representation]

This is how the native view looks like (Wrong Result):

[image: wrong representation]

---

UPDATE 1:

As suggested by @Monomachus, I updated the CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep span.mat-button-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-self: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    align-self: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    background-color: purple;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.customFontH
{
  font-family: farmaH24;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 150%;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-self: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
  align-self: center;
}
```

But the issue is still there, the web view is still correct and the native one is still buggy.

Comment: Had you tried flex to achieve that? I think something like 
```css
display: flex;
align-items: center; // or play with align-content, align-self
```
should do the trick

Comment: I tried using both, the problem is still there. It seems that the SPAN has 100% of the button height and does not follow the css TRANSFORM command